# How do i create a android x86 ISO file with a specific apk built into it?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, iso, android-x86

I have an app built in android studio i want to include in android x86 8.1.0 r6 ISO file. I got the source for it from the android x86 documentation, but i can't find any tutorials on how to inlude my apk in the build.

Does anyone know how to do it or where i can find info about it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it as a prebuilt apk in the source code.
Using soong build system, you need to create an Android.bp to define the android_app_import target with name and apk path. And finally include the package name in the PRODUCT_PACKAGES += variable in your .mk file which already is included in build system.

Example: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-13.0.0_r30:device/google/atv/LeanbackSampleApp/Android.bp;l=14